# Не работает javascript в нативном браузере Android

Tags: javascript, android

Не работает javascript в нативном браузере Android. Притом проблема не в браузере, потому что на других сайтах js работает. Проблема у данного сайта: http://trotuar-market.ru Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина.

Comment: смотри что пишет консоль браузера.

Comment: Для этого отладка существует, прежде всего консоль и алерты, а также пробуйте разные версии, сомневаюсь, что на Android 6.0 он не работает, а вот на <4.4 запросто.

Comment: @Rou1997, алерты для отладки - это жестоко

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но консоли в нативном браузере на Android нет, как и режима разработчика, чтобы отлаживать с консолью на компе (в отличие от Chrome). @Rou1997

Comment: Можно перехватить событие `window.onerror` и юзать вышеупомянутый `alert`

Comment: @Grundy зато алерты везде работают и консоль открывать не надо. Прикол в том, что я реверс-инженер и кроме консоли могу и бряки ставить, даже там, где дебаггер не очень охотно это позволяет (например, когда нет исходников - это не про JS, разумеется). И тем не менее - алерты незаменимы =)